# How can I wait for my "request" and response back to front end?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, adonis.js, zoom-sdk

I am working on the Zoom API now. I want to send my token from ZOOM API to front-end as a response. However, "token from request" is always printed first and undefined! Then the token from Zoon API" will be followed with the token. How can I make it happen? Thx!

```
const Newrequest = require("request");

class ZoomController {
  async getInvLink({ request, response }) {
const instructor_id = params.id;
try {
  let tokenRes;
  const code = request.all().code;
  console.log("the code from frontend is ", code);
  const client_id = _something_
  const client_secret = _something_
  var options = {
    method: "POST",
    url: "https://api.zoom.us/oauth/token",
    qs: {
      grant_type: "authorization_code",
      code: code,
      redirect_uri: _something_
    },
    headers: {
      Authorization:
        "Basic " +
        Buffer.from(client_id + ":" + client_secret).toString("base64")
    }
  };

  await Newrequest(options, function(error, res, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    tokenRes = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log("token from Zoon API",tokenRes);
  });

  console.log("token from request",tokenRes);
  return response.status(200).send(tokenRes);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
  return response.status(401).send();
}
```

Comment: you can't just await a function call and expect it to actually wait on it, not knowing whether or not it returns a promise.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what this api is, but I'm going to make an educated guess that `Newrequest` doesn't return a promise. So awaiting it isn't actually what you want to do.

What you can do, however, is use some simple code to turn it into a promise:

```
const tokenRes = await new Promise((resolve, reject) =>  {
    Newrequest(options, function(error, res, body) {
      if (error) reject(error);
      tokenRes = JSON.parse(body);
      console.log("token from Zoon API",tokenRes);
      resolve(tokenRes);
    });
})
```

Comment: Isn't it an antipattern to use await on a promise constructor?

Comment: sorry, here is he newrequest: const Newrequest = require("request");

Comment: you should consider using the `request-promise` library. That way you can `await` them out of the box

Answer (score 0):

You would have to listen to an endpoint at *something* and you will receive the code over there. This is the code you can send to exchange for an access token.

Answer (score 0):

Please consult this link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#promises--asyncawait

#### You can convert a regular function that takes a callback to return a promise instead with [`util.promisify()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

Example :

```js
Newrequest(options, function(error, res, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    tokenRes = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log("token from Zoon API",tokenRes);
});

// to

const util = require('util');

const req = util.promisify(Newrequest)
const data = await req(options)
// ...
```

*It's a sample code. Please adapt with your needs*

Useful course : https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/node/promisify

#### Request library is [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142)

It would be interesting to use another library.

Alternatives :

- [Got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got)
- [Axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios)
- [Node-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch)
- [superagent](https://www.npmjs.com/package/superagent)